Why probabilities of naive binary classifier doesn't sum up to 1?
Consider a disease test with false positive probability $0.01$ and false negative probability $0.2$. More over lets suppose that 20% of population is really infected.
Patient tested two times. We want to know whether is he really diseased. Let's say some patient tested two times with $x_1=1, x_2=-1$ where $x=1$ means positive test result and $x=-1$ means negative test result.
By bayes probability we can conclude that
$$
P(y=1|x_1 = 1, x_2=-1) = p(y=1)p(x_1=1|y=1)p(x_2=-1|y=1) \\
= 0.2 \cdot \overbrace{(1 - 0.2)}^{\text{true positive}} \cdot \overbrace{0.2}^{\text{false negative}} = 0.032
$$
And the same for case when $y=-1$, ie patient not infected
$$
P(y=-1|x_1 = 1, x_2=-1) = p(y=-1)p(x_1=1|y=-1)p(x_2=-1|y=-1) \\
= 0.8 \cdot \overbrace{(0.01)}^{\text{false positive}} \cdot \overbrace{(1 - 0.2)}^{\text{true negative}} = 0.064
$$
Do I get it right that these probabilities doesn't sum up to 1, because I don't consider other combinations of $x_1, x_2$ and once I do probabilities will sum up to 1?

What you do is wrong. You consider a restricted universe : only people who have a 1st test positive, and 2nd test negative. All people from these restricted universe are either ill, either safe. So P(ill)+P(safe) should be 1.

To solve this question in a simple way, you can consider a population with $1 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$ people.

Total $= 1 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$

We know that 20% are really infected :

Infected $= 200 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$ ,
Safe $= 800 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$

We run 1st test, this test is positive, and probability of false positive is 0.01, probability of false negative is 0.2

Infected, first test positive $= 160 \thinspace 000\thinspace 000$
Safe, first test positive $= 8 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$

Our patient is one of those $= 160 \thinspace 000\thinspace 000 + 8 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000$ peoples.
2nd test is negative :

Infected, first test positive, 2nd test negative $= 160 \thinspace 000\thinspace 000 \times 0.2 = 32 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 $
Safe, first test positive, 2nd test negative $= 8 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 \times (1-0.01)= 7 \thinspace 920 \thinspace 000$

Total number of people with 1st test positive and 2nd test negative $=32 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 + 7 \thinspace 920 \thinspace 000 = 39 \thinspace 920 \thinspace 000$.
Probability that our patient is really infected $= \dfrac {32 \thinspace 000 \thinspace 000 }{39 \thinspace 920 \thinspace 000}$
